# You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page while making a plugin

Tags: php

You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page. This is the error i am facing while making my own plugin.Actually, i want to link to another page.

Wordpress version is 3.8.1
I made a plugin that shows the following display(the index page of my crud plugin)
[image]

I want the Add New link to redirect to other create.php(which is in the same folder as crud.php the index php file).But it says You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.
Is it correct the way i link to create.php file inside my plugin folder?
I tried to read abt cross page call in wordpress but no luck.
I tried different plugin video tutorial every video ends in the same page.
I want to be redirected to the create.php page with the same sidebar and topbar in crud page.
And of course i have nicely embeded the html code and php code it's just i did not know the way to show them nicely here.
I want a redirect to prevent from inserting data to my table everytime the page is refreshed.
And my folder struncture is as follows

[image]

The code is as follows

```
add_action('admin_menu','crudindex');
function crudindex(){
    add_options_page('Crud Dashboard', 'Crudboard', 'manage_options', 'crud', 'crudboard');
}

function crudboard()
{
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>
            Motors
            <a class="add_new-h2" href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=create">Add New</a>

        </h2>
        <table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed pages">
        </table>
}
```

I know this is a repeat question.I post it beacause i didn't find the correct answer.
Thanks

Comment: Can you link us to the original question you repeated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118067/wordpressplugin-erroryou-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-pa

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function crudindex(){
   add_options_page('Crud Dashboard', 'Crudboard', 'manage_options', 'crud', 'crudboard');
   add_options_page(NULL, 'Crudboard', 'manage_options', 'create_crud', 'crudboard');
}
```

and your anchor tag like

```
<a class="add_new-h2" href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=create_crud">Add New</a>
```

Comment: but if i do add_options_page twice then it will make two options in settings which i do not want.What i want is that Add New link redirects to the create.php page which has all the sidebar and top admin bar like crud.php has and it will display an add form.

Comment: when first parameter is NULL it's not display in left sidebar navigation

Comment: it has already been displayed when i tried your code.And The place where you provide NULL isn't the Page Title param value

Comment: What is your wordpress version?

Comment: It is 3.8.1 and is also mentioned in my question above

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do that

```
function crudindex(){
   add_options_page('Crud Dashboard', 'Crudboard', 'manage_options', 'crud', 'crudboard');
   add_options_page('Crudboard', 'Crudboard', 'manage_options', 'create_crud', 'crudboard');
}


function remove_submenus() {
   global $submenu;
   echo "<pre>" . print_r($submenu['options-general.php'], true) . "</pre>";
   unset($submenu['options-general.php'][your-menu-array-key]);
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_submenus');
```

Above will show all sub navigation under settings you find your menu position key and replace with your-menu-array-key

Comment: it is not going the way i want, is it?  First i don't want two menu in settings panel and second you are telling me to remove that menu where it should no be in first place

Comment: so, you need use another way like <a class="add_new-h2" href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=crud&type=add">Add New</a>

Comment: if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == 'add') {
//Create form here
} else {
//listing data here
}

Comment: yes all i want is that <a>Add New </a> link should redirect to my create.php file where i caan show a form and submit.And after submitting i want either to the edit page or index(crud.php) page with a msg "successfully inserted".

Comment: i have done that but that inserts the data to my tbl even if i refresh the page where i need is a page redirect to prevent it.